# Issues using 3306 port in a SQL Server database connection string from a SSIS dtsx package

Tags: sql-server, security, ssis

I have created an SSIS dtsx package that connects to a remote SQL Server database.The remote network is configured so that the connection to the DB can be made indistinctly through ports 1435 and 3306.

Neither of the two connection string to the remote DB gives problems if the connection is executed from my PC either through SQL Server Management Studio or from a Windows desktop application. But when I run the dtsx package it only works if the port used in the connection string is 1435.

Do you know if there is any security configuration a

Comment: If it listens on port 3306 are you sure it's a Microsoft SQL Server? Port 3306 is the default port for MySQL instances.

Comment: Thanks. I know it's not a usual port configuration for a MS Sql Server but i'm sure both ports 1435 and 3306 are configured so that a remote client can connect this Sql Server.

Comment: By default Windows Firewall with Advanced Security tends to be configured with ingress (incoming traffic) and egress (outgoing traffic) rules but only the ingress rules are active. It could be that the server running your DTSX package has egress rules active and it may have rules allowing tcp/1435 but not tcp/3306 traffic.

Comment: Thanks. To check for those kinds of firewall rules, I first tested both connection  strings (ports 1435 an 3306) from two "normal" SQL-Server clients (a SQL-Server Management Studio and a Windows desktop application). No issues were detected. Instead, the DTSX package ran the same test but without success on port 3306. I suppose it must be some kind of DTSX level configuration .